# Compute the CR for lightweight temporal compression

Tags: c, compression, temporal, lossy-compression

I am working on the LTC algorithm to compress the data

```
int SIZE =256;
int data[SIZE ]={700,...};  // input dataset (original data)
```

After executed the LTC I get on output (compressed data) like this:

```
//format: "number:count" --> e.g., 511:4

700:1
812:15
511:4
117:25
905:25
117:25
905:25
117:25
```

How can I compute the compression ratio for this output (the compressed data)?

```
 // CR = Original/ compressed 
float CR = ((int)(SIZE*(sizeof(int)))/?);
```

Comment: It's unclear what your output represents. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Write output to a file in the form you want and ask the OS how big the file is.  What you show could be 54  or 62 or 108 bytes, depending how it is written.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, The output represents the data after compression (compressed data)

Comment: @ayla the just count the output bytes. What specific problem do you have?

Comment: Are you actually compressing the data or just getting information about the data?

Comment: Please show what compressed data following sequence would give: `2,3,3,5,5,5`. Would it be `2:1, 3:2, 5:3`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, according to this format (format: "number:count" --> e.g., 511:4) the
number represents the compressed value, and the count represents the number of values that represented by a single number.

Comment: @ayla please answer the question I asked in my previous comment by "yes" or "no", and if it's "no" explain.

Comment: So, my question: When I compute the CR I should depend on just the "number"? without the count, is that right?

Comment: The output for this sequence 2,3,3,5,5,5 is 2:6

Comment: @ayla the compression ration is usually the amount of compressed data divided by the amount of uncompressed data.

Comment: @ayla _The output for this sequence 2,3,3,5,5,5 is 2:6_ Huh? I'm giving up.

Comment: @ayla Tip: `(int)(SIZE*(sizeof(int)))` replaceable with `sizeof data`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes "2,3,3,5,5,5 is 2:6" is unusual, yet LTC is lossy and "3,3,5,5,5" is part of the trend.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I compute the compression ratio

```
// Size of one "number:count" pair.
size_t size_of_number_count = sizeof size_t + sizeof data[0];

// Number of "number:count" pairs.
size_t compressed_count = 8;

// CR = Original/ compressed 
double CR = 1.0 * sizeof data / (compressed_count * size_of_number_count);
```

Comment: Is the calculation of the `size_of_number_count` value just an example, or does it match some actual implementation? Are there any implementations that store each number:count pair in a variable-length format (so that `size_of_number_count` would not be constant over the data set)?

Comment: @IanAbbott A sample.  As the goal is the ratio of a _compression_, it is reasonable to assume the compressed data lacks padding or unused elements. I suppose code could use a slightly more correct/pessimistic: `double CR = 1.0 * sizeof data / (compressed_count * size_of_number_count + sizeof compressed_count);`.